# Need help rewriting a C macro as a function

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I need some help rewriting the following line in a more type safe way and rewriting it as a function, however the fact that this code is defined inside a function is making it hard for me to think of a clever way of doing it because apparently it would involve declaring several arguments.

```
#define CHECK(id) if(table->cells[id]) isgood[table->cells[id]-1] = 0;
```

where `table` is a `struct` and `isgood` is an `int`.

Comment: Be careful with "clever" programming; if debugging is four times as hard as coding, then you should avoid writing clever code: debugging it becomes exceptionally hard. (By the way, why are you tagged as C *and* C++?)

Comment: Why is this a macro in the first place? Does it occur multiple times in the code?

Comment: isgood is an int?  Or is it an int[]?

Comment: @ojrac: "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it." – Brian W. Kernighan

Answer (score 5):

Straight translation (if table->cells[id] is int):

```
void check(int id, int*isgood) { if (id) isgood[id-1] = 0; }
```

Call with:

```
check(table->cells[id], isgood);
```

However, I'd rename/rework this a bit.  I'd especially change the name.  There is also no error checking - ie, if table->cells[id]==0, you're going to try to set isgood[-1], which would be bad.

Answer (score 4):

> apparently it would involve declaring
>   several arguments

What is wrong with that?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just a function that receives `table` and `id` and does this?

```
void foo(TableType & t, int id)
{
    if (t.cells[id]) 
        isgood[t.cells[id]-1] = 0;
}
```

p.s.

It's a bad macro indeed. The name is very misleading.

p.p.s.

The whole thing is rather weird and the logic of this function escapes me. What exactly is this supposed to achieve?

Comment: You would need to pass in the isgood array as well, unless it is global.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working in C++, I'd consider making check a member function of the table, which seems like a good candidate for a class:

```
class Table {
    //...
    public bool check(int id) {
        if (this->cells[id]) {
            this->isGood[id] = 0;
            // the line you have, isgood[table->cells[id]-1] = 0 looks buggy:
            // you treat table->cells[id] as a true/false value one line ago;
            // probably not a valid array index? I'm taking a stab at what to do.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or maybe cells[id] is a bunch of pointers to cell structs, and null ones are empty? I sort of suspect check(id) should return this->cells[id], and it'll be used in a loop to initialize the isGood array... but in my answer, I tried to stick close to what his macro was doing.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally a good idea not to refer to variables in a macro.

First, make sure the name is meaningful. what are you checking for? And is there a side effect?

```
void update_valid_cells(Table& table, int id, BoolArray& validArray)
{
     if(table.cells[id]==NULL) return;
     validArray[id]-1=false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think C99 can qualify functions as *inline* so you get the speedup of no-function-call without using macros. Also, most C compilers support extensions such as __inline for this purpose.